# Why does browser show smaller favicon?

Tags: icons, favicon

In our [client's website](http://icando.ru), [favicon.ico](http://icando.ru/favicon.ico) file has several sizes from 8x8 to 32x32. I expect the 16x16 to show in browser tab, but instead it shows 8x8 icon in white frame. Why does this happen and what workarounds are there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Favicon should be 16x16 or 32x32 at 8-bit or 24-bit, according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Standardization_and_implementation

But in my experience, try to get the favicon to have file size 1.12KB like Google, StackOverflow etc :P

Answer (score 2):

try clearing cache and rebooting. See [here](http://www.zen-cart.com/forum/showthread.php?t=126877&page=2)

Answer (score 0):

Your favicon is 24 X 24, try making it 32 X 32.